# (C++)What's wrong with my Romove(x) Function about AVL-Tree? It caused some interrupts when I test it

Tags: c++, data-structures, avl-tree

I create an **AVL-Tree** with **25 random integers**, and I hope to **delete** each integer in its original order.
 So every time I delete a number, I take a InOrderTraverse. But it causes some **interrupts** and I find that the list of InOrderTraverse does not decrease one by one, it has some **chasms** like this( see delete 143 and 564):

```
Create AVL-Tree：
279 302 225 801 299 416 72 91 738 150 629 265 343 456 63 347 143 564 908 930 616 715 169 36 67
InOrderTraverse：
36 63 67 72 91 143 150 169 225 265 279 299 302 343 347 416 456 564 616 629 715 738 801 908 930
Remove:
delete：279     Traverse： 36 63 67 72 91 143 150 169 225 265 299 302 343 347 416 456 564 616 629 715 738 801 908 930
delete：302     Traverse： 36 63 67 72 91 143 150 169 225 265 299 343 347 416 456 564 616 629 715 738 801 908 930
delete：225     Traverse： 36 63 67 72 91 143 150 169 265 299 343 347 416 456 564 616 629 715 738 801 908 930
delete：801     Traverse： 36 63 67 72 91 143 150 169 265 299 343 347 416 456 564 616 629 715 738 908 930
delete：299     Traverse： 36 63 67 72 91 143 150 169 265 343 347 416 456 564 616 629 715 738 908 930
delete：416     Traverse： 36 63 67 72 91 143 150 169 265 343 347 456 564 616 629 715 738 908 930
delete：72      Traverse： 36 63 67 91 143 150 169 265 343 347 456 564 616 629 715 738 908 930
delete：91      Traverse： 36 63 67 143 150 169 265 343 347 456 564 616 629 715 738 908 930
delete：738     Traverse： 36 63 67 143 150 169 265 343 347 456 564 616 629 715 908 930
delete：150     Traverse： 36 63 67 143 169 265 343 347 456 564 616 629 715 908 930
delete：629     Traverse： 36 63 67 143 169 265 343 347 456 564 616 715 908 930
delete：265     Traverse： 36 63 67 143 169 343 347 456 564 616 715 908 930
delete：343     Traverse： 36 63 67 143 169 347 456 564 616 715 908 930
delete：456     Traverse： 36 63 67 143 169 347 564 616 715 908 930
delete：63      Traverse： 36 67 143 169 347 564 616 715 908 930
delete：347     Traverse： 36 67 143 169 564 616 715 908 930
delete：143     Traverse： 36 67 169 564 616 715 908 930
delete：564     Traverse： 36 67 169 616 715
delete：908     Traverse： 36 67 169 616 715
delete：930     Traverse： 36 67 169 616 715
delete：616     Traverse： 36 67 169 715
delete：715     Traverse： 36 67 169
delete：169     Traverse： 36 67
delete：36      Traverse：
```

I have checked my textbook and searched on the Internet, but it still has not been resolved.
I hope you can help me. Many thanks!
Below is the complete code:https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SD3pDnYNJY/

Comment: Please pick one language, then post a [mcve] of your code in the question

Comment: It is C++. I try to post my code here, but it can be allowed because the code contains Chinese characters in code's comment.

Comment: your whole code is too much. Instead of posting it all you should prepare a small example that demonstrates your current problem but nothing else (ie any method that is not called can be removed). Thats what we call a [mcve]

Comment: @CHINEW *I have checked my textbook and searched on the Internet* -- The next step is for you to use the debugger to debug your program.  Single step through your code with the debugger, and identify where the program diverges from the expected behavior.  Then make the appropriate adjustments to the program (or determine that the approach is wrong and needs to be redone).  That's how programmers are supposed to work -- if there is an error in their program, they debug the program.

Comment: Definitely include a formatted code example. I will not follow that link.